# How to load images from custom domains to next.config.js for "next/image"/

Tags: nginx, next.js, nextjs-image

I have two hostings, one is running nextjs on the domen.com. On the second img.domain.com.
And i use  `<Image src='img.domain.com/test.png' width="200" height="50" />`
I get the error:

```
FetchError: request to https://img.domain.com/test.png failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
```

Beacuse, if i open via a direct link, then the pictures open, but with the parameters &w=1200&q=75 they do not open. Nging get the error **404 Not Found**

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {   
    images: {
        domains: ['img.domain.com']
    },
}
```

Comment: use two domain  | domains: ['img.domain.com' , '.domain.com'] |

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the full domain inside the src attribute.
Something like the following

```
<Image src='https://img.domain.com/test.png' width="200" height="50" />
```

Hope this helps.